# If you check Groupisomorphism - does the operation, under which the Groups are closed, matter?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

For example: $G_1=(R,+) \quad G_2=(R_+,x)$
So the first group are the Real Number closed under addition and the second group are the positive Real Numbers closed under multiplication.
My Lector said that the Isomorphism was $f(x)=e^x$ because its a bijection and $e^(x+y)=e^xe^y$.
However, if the 2 Groups were not closed under addition and multiplication would the Groups still be isomorphic? (Btw: I did my research but I didnt really know what I should search for.)

Comment: A group is always closed under its operation.

Comment: @dREaM I mean if in this case the Real Numbers werent closed under addition but, for example, multiplication, so: $G_1=(R,x) \quad G_2=(R_+,x)$. Would there still be the Groupisomorphism between the two Groups?

Comment: No, because the real with multipication has element of order $2$.

Comment: @DavidBeck: $(\mathbb{R}, \times)$ is not a group.

Comment: Anyway the answer to the question is yes, the group operation does matter.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Why is it not a group? There are inverses, a identity, and you only get elements of the group by multiplying Real Number.

Comment: @DavidBeck: Zero doesn't have an inverse.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese You are right. Did not think about that. but if you'd take the Real Numbers without zero - would it be Isomorphic?

Comment: The groups $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}, \times)$ and $(\mathbb{R}_+, \times)$ are not isomorphic for the reason Ofir Schnabel stated in his comment above. There are two elements in the first group which square to the identity (namely $1$ and $-1$), but there is only one such element in the second group (namely $1$).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I see. Thank you for your time.